# Change the application icon theme but not changing the panel icons

Tags: unity, themes, icons

Downloading and setting a new icon theme modifies the top panel icons. I want to keep the panel icons (`Ubuntu-mono-dark` theme).

> [image]

Is that possible? How can I change the applications/folders & files icon theme (for example  *Moka* theme), but keeping the default top panel icons (*Ubuntu-mono-dark*)?

After setting Moka theme, the panel icons are changed, and I don't like them.

> [image]

Comment: Not having done this before I am not quite sure if it would work, but you could try overwriting the `status` folder of your custom theme with the ubuntu mono status folder (located at `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light` or `.../ubuntu-mono-dark`).

Comment: Which icon theme are you trying to use?

Comment: @Wilf Moka theme. See the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did it for me

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Icons in the 'Use another icon set while keeping the Ubuntu Mono panel icons' section.

1. Press ALT+F2 and type "gksu nautilus /usr/share/icons".
2. Make a copy of the "ubuntu-mono-dark" or "ubuntu-mono-light" folder.
3. Rename the folder to a new name.
4. Open the index.theme file
5. Change the "Name" field to a new name ("Name=Ubuntu-Mono-Dark" to "Name=My-New-Icons")
6. Change "Inherits" field to the name of the icon theme you want to use ‘Inherits=Humanity-Dark,gnome,hicolor’ to the name of the folder of the icons you want to use.(This folder may be in ~/.icons or in /usr/share/icons)
7. Save the file and go to appearance preferences to set the new icon theme.